# Magento 2.3.3 Tax calculation wrong

Tags: magento2, tax-calculation

I have a german store, therefore we must calculate 19% tax on every product. I've setup every settings to ensure that would happen, but for any reason only 15.97% are calculated. Please take a look at the images below, maybe you guys find something i havent seen...

Product price is 100€, so the calculated tax should be 19€, but 15.97€ are displayed as tax on the order summary.

**Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax**

[image: Tax Configuration]

**Stores -> Tax Rules**

[image: Tax Rules]

**Stores -> Tax Zones and Rates**

[image]

***EDIT***

After taking a closer look at the tax rate of 15.97 I saw a pattern there, if you substract 19% of 19 you will get 15.966 which gehts rounded by magento to 15.97, so my tax rate gets taxed for some reason, anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set your catalog prices to **including tax**

If the product price including tax is 100 and the tax rate is 19% then the product price excluding tax is 84.03 and the tax amount is 15.97. 84.03 + 15.97 = 100

Your tax calculation is correct.

Comment: Just realized i messed up big times there. I tried to check it by calculating it backwards, therefore my calculation was incorrect and i thought the tax calculation itself is incorrect too... Thank you very much.